# Placed an image beside the image banner on the right

Tags: html, css, jpeg, division

I am trying to figured and trying to workout to placed an image file beside the image page banner but it is not displayed as what is expected

**html**

```
<div class="slider">
 <ul class= "banner">
    <li><img src ="image.jpg"/></li>
     <li><img src ="image1.jpg"/><li>
</ul>

</div>
```

and this this is an image i coded to be shown on the right),It was placed after div

```
<ul>
<li> <img src="test.jbg"><li>
</ul>
```

I want to add an image which is not in the page banner to be  displayed on the top right which is align to the image slide banner

But the problem  it always displayed on the bottom of the image slider

**css**

```
.rslides {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }

.rslides li {
   position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  }

.rslides li:first-child {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  }

.rslides img {
    float: left;
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 10px solid #454545;
  }
```

to put in image
[Slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmUT7.jpg)

The one i shaded in yellow, is not inline with my image slide..all i need to be in same line as banner however it always displayed as second line

Comment: Can you explain it in an image?

Comment: make a jsfiddle please.

Comment: @pedram image has been added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, i just added style attribute in div element:

```
<div style="float:left;" class="slider">
<ul class= "banner">
<li><img src ="p1.png"/></li>
<li><img src ="p2.jpg"/><li>
</ul>

</div>

<ul>
<li> <img src="p3.jpg"><li>
</ul>

<style>
.rslides {
position: relative;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

.rslides li {
position: absolute;
display: none;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
top: 0;
}

.rslides li:first-child {
position: relative;
float: left;
}

.rslides img {
float: left;
border: 0;
width: 100%;
border-top: 10px solid #454545;
}
</style>
```